# window.location.href does not work in Internet Explorer with XLS files

Tags: internet-explorer, xls

I have a legacy application that, at some point, generates the following code in one of its pages:

```
window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/myApplication/manuals/charts.xls";
```

When Mozilla sees this, it opens a download dialog with "open with...\save as..." options.

IE (v7 and v8) does not open a dialog. It takes the file and just renders it in the page, like some HTML; but it's a binary file, so all you see is garbage on the screen.

Has anyone encountered this before?

EDIT1: This  works on some IE browser but not on all. I am thinking a configuration issue with IE. Also, for `.ppt` and `.doc` files it works, the issue is just for `.xls` files.

EDIT2: Even if I place a link in the page like:

```
click <a href="http://localhost:8080/myApplication/manuals/charts.xls">here</a> for the XLS
```

it won’t display the dialog box when I click on it. It just gets written in the page.

Comment: Differences in IE is a red herring.  It may depend on whether Excel is installed on that machine, etc., but IE won't even try to handle it natively if your web server is correctly identifying the content as something to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your web server is sending the correct MIME type for the xls file.

Look for a directory `WEB-INF` with a file `web.xml`.  Add this to the file, within the `web-app` element:

```
<mime-mapping>
  <extension>xls</extension>
  <mime-type>application/octet-stream</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Comment: This file sits on the server, in the "manuals" folder in the application's context directory. It is accessed as presented in the question. Even if I enter "http://localhost:8080/myApplication/manuals/charts.xls" in IE's address bar I still get garbage on the screen instead of a download dialog. I can’t set "Content-disposition" headers, it's just like a link.

Comment: The Content-disposition header will be set by your web server.  Are you using IIS?  Apache? Tomcat?

Comment: OK, I added instructions for configuring the mime-type.